# Delete matching values from csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

Using DictReader and DictWriter I need to find matching values between file1.csv and file2.csv. If a match is found, remove it from file1.csv

file1.csv

```
UserName,LastIP,LastLogon
Jessica_Alba,10.10.10.11,11/14/2019
Karen_Edwards,10.10.10.12,11/14/2019
Tracy_Chung,10.10.10.25,11/15/2019
```

file2.csv

```
Department,UserName,LastPasswordReset,LastIP
IT,Jessica_Alba,9/14/2019,10.10.10.11
Accounting,Karen_Edwards,9/14/2019,10.10.10.12
```

Expected output after comparison of two files that file1.csv is updated by removing the matching users

```
UserName,LastIP,LastLogon
Tracy_Chung,10.10.10.25,11/15/2019
```

However, it doesn't seem to the case with my code. What am I doing wrong?

```
data3 = []

with open("file1.csv","r") as in_file1, open("file2.csv", "r") as in_file2:
    reader1 = csv.DictReader(in_file1)
    reader2 = csv.DictReader(in_file2)
    for row2 in reader2:
        for row1 in reader1:
            print(row1['UserName'])
            if row2['UserName'] != row1['UserName']:

                data3.append(row1)


print(data3)
```

Comment: For the first row in `reader2` your code is iterating over all rows of `reader1` and `row2` is appended to `data3` every time, except for the one time the usernames are equal.

Comment: @Wups I made a typo in the code. It's supposed to be row1.

Comment: What @Wups is trying to say is that there is a more fundamental error in your logic. You would be adding the same user many times, if it weren't for the fact that the loop is empty for other reasons (see my answer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An open file handle is a stream; you can read as long as there are more lines you have not read, but once you have read all the lines, once, you are at the end of the stream, and further reads will produce nothing at all.

Rather than attempt to loop over the inner file more than once, read it into memory, then loop as many times as you like over the data structure you have in memory ... or better yet, produce a data structure in memory which lets you directly see if the user was present in the second file, so you don't have to loop at all to search for a user.

```py
import csv


data3 = []

with open("file2.csv", "r") as in_file2:
    reader2 = csv.DictReader(in_file2)
    # Create a set of users
    users = {row2['UserName'] for row2 in reader2}

with open("file1.csv","r") as in_file1:
    reader1 = csv.DictReader(in_file1)
    for row1 in reader1:
        if row1['UserName'] not in users:
            data3.append(row1)

print(data3)
```